# Rails Routing to Unknown Pages is Messing Up With ActiveStorage Image Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I searched for every code that I can find here in stackoverflow on how you actually can redirect the pages that doesn't exist or unknown to a 404 page.

For instance you visited this page  `http://localhost:3000/thispageisnull` since the page doesn't exist it will automatically redirect you to the default 404 custom page I created.

So far here's what I did. On my `errors_controller.rb` file I place this code:

```
def show_404
      render "404", status: 404
    end
```

And then on my `routes.rb` file, I place this code:

```
match '*path', via: :all, to: 'errors#show_404'
```

This basically works for me as it redirects all of the unknown pages to 404 page. However, it seems it's messing up with the ActiveStorage images path.

Whenever I am placing these codes and redirecting every page that doesn't exist to 404, it's always making my ActiveStorage images broken. As in like this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD0j0.jpg

And if I remove these piece of codes about the 404 redirection, it always turn back to normal images.

What is the best way to do a redirection to 404 page w/o affecting the ActiveStorage images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try doing something like this which might help, in your `routes.rb` change the line like this:

```
match '*path', via: :all, to: 'errors#show_404', constraints: lambda { |req|
    req.path.exclude? 'rails/active_storage'
}
```

So it will exclude that path and let the application show the images. Please change the path as per your requirement (I think it should be `rails/active_storage` only)

Comment: This works like a charm. I did not knew that you can insert lambda and exlude rails/active _storage on routes. Thanks.

Follow up question though are there any other form on routes like this that I can use to do do the same effect? Thank you so much!

Comment: I am not sure if this would work or I have not tried to implement it yet but you can try this and see if you succeed in implementing routing constraints for activestorage: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints

Comment: This worked for me. I believe this problem began for me when I upgraded to Rails 7. I wonder if earlier versions of Rails put active storage routes higher in priority somehow? In any case, excluding `rails/active_storage` worked. I also excluded the other Rails routes that would be caught, like `action_mailbox`.